# Highcharts json data date in zulu time not working

Tags: highcharts

I was trying to follow this demo https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/data/livedata-rows

But can not understand why the date/time is not showing up correctly for me I have it in the exact same format and only changed the link in this example to a local host where I am serving my json file this is what my json looks like

```
{
  "vtg": [
    ["2021-06-18T16:46:38.981Z", 7.131307519877803],
    ["2021-06-18T16:46:39.981Z", 6.728442167327733],
    ["2021-06-18T16:46:40.981Z", 1.272020585570508],
    ["2021-06-18T16:46:41.981Z", 6.80643850015173],
    ["2021-06-18T16:46:42.981Z", 3.493474821467808],
    ["2021-06-18T16:46:43.981Z", 2.1728923419279234],
    ["2021-06-18T16:46:44.981Z", 8.33079253512965],
    ["2021-06-18T16:46:45.981Z", 6.068523773578017],
    ["2021-06-18T16:46:46.981Z", 5.704502768230142],
    ["2021-06-18T16:46:47.981Z", 1.6336430526049028]
  ],}
```

In the example it has the time on the bottom axis and when you hover it gives the full date and time but when I try it with mine the bottom axis becomes 0-10 and the tool-tip shows the exact string. To check I even followed the link in the example that it was pulling data from to make sure the time was formatted correctly but I cant seem to find what I did wrong.

Comment: Right now I am just testing my files so my json is not live updating at this current moment That is really the only thing I see different from the example to mine.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation you can find that the data should be structured as a row array:

> A URL to a remote JSON dataset, structured as a row array. Will be fetched when the chart is created using Ajax.

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.rowsURL

Meanwhile, your data structure is an object: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/80btkhgx/

```
  series: [{
    data: data['vtg']
  }]
```

Comment: In your example the x axis labels and tool-tip labels dont convert to  hours seconds minutes either like it does in the demo which is what I am trying to achive or are you trying to say that mine wont work in converting the time unless i am using Ajaxs?

Comment: The x values in your data are not a date format, it's just a string. You will need to convert it.

Comment: but that how they have it formatted in the Json they are using for the demo. would I need to convert it in the Json or is their a way to convert it through highcharts?

Comment: @ChillHat you can parse it also on the front side, before the data will be applied to the chart: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gnv79xwu/